# Understanding the syntax for creating a function

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a function (simple one).

My original table:

```
CREATE TABLE a
(
    row_count int IDENTITY (1,1) primary key,
    name varchar(200) NOT NULL
    products varchar(200) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO a (name, products)
VALUES ('ABC', 'A1'), ('ABC', 'A2'),
       ('EDF', 'A1'), ('EDF', 'A3');
```

The sample table

```
name  products
---------------
ABC   A1
ABC   A2
EDF   A1
EDF   A3
```

Please ignore my purpose, I just want to practice with function.

My expectation for this function

```
select * 
from divide_by_name(a, name, ABC)
```

which should return a result of:

```
name  products
----------------
ABC   A1
ABC   A2
```

I want to create a function that create a table from information I input such as `table_name`, `column_name` and `name` (of another table). My code so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION divide_by_name 
    (@table_name varchar(100),
     @column_name varchar(100),
     @name varchar(100))
RETURNS table
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @table_name TABLE (table_name varchar(100), 
                               products varchar(100)
                              ),
            @column_name vachar(100),
            @name varchar(100)

    (SELECT * 
     FROM @table_name
     WHERE @column_name = @name)
END
```

It got this error

> The variable name '@table_name' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

If I deleted the `DECLARE` statement. I got this

> Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'

Comment: This is a common mistake, but you can't parameterize object names like tables or columns. This requires dynamic SQL, and that can't be done from functions, only stored procedures. In general, when you find yourself writing super-generic code like this, you usually need to rethink your approach -- dynamic SQL is a big burden on maintenance and security (think SQL injection). If you have plenty of time to spare, here's a [full article](http://sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) on the subject of dynamic SQL, in particular when you [should not use it](http://sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Badcases).

Comment: The fact you want to do this (in a function) suggests you have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) as well. Even more so, as you **can't** use dynamic SQL in a Function.

Comment: Additionally to previous comments, you are trying to merge Inline Table-Valued Function Syntax and Multi-Statement Table-Valued Function Syntax [CREATE FUNCTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax)

Comment: Also, more generally, if you're used to programming languages, please don't think of SQL in general (and T-SQL in particular, the dialect SQL Server uses) as programming languages. They technically are, but they offer very little in the way of modularity, code reuse and all that nice stuff you'd be using in "real" programming languages. Quite often, copy-pasting code with minor modifications is actually the "right" way to do it, in terms of performance and maintainability (notwithstanding that you should use things like views, subqueries and table-valued functions where possible, of course).

Comment: And as a side-note, you should declare types that are to hold table names, column names, and other schema related names as "sysname", which is technically nvarchar(128), to avoid implicit casting, type mismatches, etc. So "DECLARE @tableName sysname;"  But again, as others have stated, you can't use a variable to hold a table name for a SELECT. SELECT must take a hard-coded table or view or table-valued function name as the argument to the FROM clause.